# Is there any better way in oracle to enable parallel other than this?

Tags: oracle, optimization, oracle-11g

I want to do do following set of operation.

```
execute immediate "alter session enable parallel query";

execute immediate "alter session enable parallel ddl";

execute immediate "alter session set parallel_force_local=false";
```

Is there any better way of doing in oracle 11g/12c?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "any better way"? What are you trying to achieve? `parallel_force_local` is only meaningful if you are actually running this in a RAC environment.

Comment: I am trying to enable parallel  for ddl. If any oracle utility is there then i need not write this inside any procedure to use it. So if its the optimised way then please share.

Comment: But parallel query and ddl are enabled by default (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/manproc006.htm) .

Answer (score 1):

You should alter your tables and indexes and specify the amount of parallel that you want.

[How Parallel Execution Works](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm)

```
ALTER TABLES sales PARALLEL 8;
ALTER TABLE customers PARALLEL 4;
```